# dumping Outlook pst file to portable format

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to dump the *entire* contents of a PST file to a portable (preferrably text) format like XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is unlikely – most programs use mbox, Maildir, vCard, LDIF, iCal – however, these are formats that are *far more common and portable* than XML for mail, calendars or contacts.

The *libpst* package comes with a few tools:

- `readpst` – messages to *mbox* or *Maildir*, contacts to vCard, calendar to vCalendar, journal entries to vJournal.
- `pst2ldif` – contacts to LDIF.

Unfortunately, its output is lacking some data (especially in case of journal entries), and it does not extract tasks or notes.

However, **Outlook itself can export any folder** in the PST as a CSV (comma-separated) file, containing every single field.

Comment: Outlook doesn't include attachments when exporting to CSV.

Comment: the readpst man page doesn't say anything about Maildir, can you give an example or point to one where this is implemented?