# How to compare the contents of two pst files that check the same email address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, comparison, pst

Is it otherwise possible to automate the comparison of two pst files?

Here's my situation... A soon-to-be ex-employee brought his laptop in so that the contents could be copied/backed up (it was a company laptop, but he'll end up with it).

There is another computer at the office checking the same email address with the same version of Outlook.

The employee deleted his personal emails prior to bringing in his laptop (he said as much).  We are trying to find out if he deleted more than just personal emails.

Of course we *have* all the emails on the machine at the office, but short of going line by line through the inbox, is there a way to compare the two pst files to find out which messages the backup is missing that the complete version has?

Comment: No free PST comparisons that I'm aware of. A 'quick and dirty' compare would be to PST all that is in the mailbox on the office PC and simply compare the size of the two files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the PST's into Outlook one at a time, and [export them to CSV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290859) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63hydenPHdQ)). Then use a [Diff utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) to compare the exported CSVs.

Perhaps check out these related SU questions:

- [Compare two spreadsheets and get missing records](https://superuser.com/questions/443267/compare-two-spreadsheets-and-get-missing-records)
- [dumping Outlook pst file to portable format](https://superuser.com/questions/377018/dumping-outlook-pst-file-to-portable-format)

Comment: That seems a reasonable way to go about it. Thanks ;)

Comment: I don't think that will work if an account has got a lot of messages; for example about 90.000.

Answer (score -1):

It is a pity that there is no comparison software to do the job.  My interest is to check that exportation of emails to a new pst file has taken place completely and accurately.  Export is useful since it will fix errors in a pst file in one hit, unlike scanpst.exe, which can need to be run several times, and will also produce a much more compact pst file than running the compactor in outlook's data file management.

I have read at https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26658072/Compare-Outlook-PST-files.html, and 4Team have confirmed it to me, that 4Team's DuplicateKiller will somehow compare the contents of pst files, but I am not sure how and could not investigate it because that program operates as an addin to Outlook, but once I had installed DuplicateKiller on my system - Outlook 2007 and XP (which 4Team say are supported) - I could not longer open Outlook except in safe mode - i.e. run outlook.exe /safe - which of course would not show the addin.

I think you will find that if you export to a csv file, you can only export one folder in the pst at a time, and not the whole .pst file.  At least, that appears to be the case with Outlook 2007.  And I suspect that exporting the contents of the messages into a csv file could get messy, though I have not taken it that far.  Perhaps a better solution would be to archive the pst files to be compared using Mailstore or Mailstore Home (the latter is free, but will only archive pst files mounted in Outlook), and then export the archive for each pst file from Mailstore or Mailstore Home to its own directory as .eml or .msg files.  The emails are then exported to the directory with subfolders etc according to the folder structure in the pst file.  The emails are numbered but do not show dates sent.  Then you could use Beyond Compare to identify the emails that do not appear in both pst files and use the copy to folder function in Beyond Compare to collect those emails in a separate directory or directories.  I have not taken it that far yet, but I think that this is basically the same method as suggested above, but using Mailstore or Mailstore Home instead of Outlook's export to csv function to work around the fact that Outlook will only export one folder at a time as a csv file.

Comment: What is your answer again?